# I need to change loan calculator from slider to input textbox

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a loan calculator it workds perfectly fine using the inout elements as slider inputs but my client wants to enter the values manually and does not want to use the slider, when i change the slider properties in my html to input box it does not work.

Here's Since my site is running on http test server you may have security error, you can bypass that and proceed to check the site.

```
<!-- content start -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="wrapper-content bg-white pinside40">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                <div class="bg-light pinside40 outline">
                                    <span>Loan Amount is </span>
                                    <strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right" id="la_value">30000</span></strong>
                                    <input type="text" data-slider="true" value="30000" data-slider-range="100000,5000000" data-slider-step="10000" data-slider-snap="true" id="la">
                                    <hr>
                                    <span>No. of Month is <strong>
                                        <span class="pull-right"  id="nm_value">30</span> </strong>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" data-slider="true" value="30" data-slider-range="120,360" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-snap="true" id="nm">
                                    <hr>
                                    <span>Rate of Interest [ROI] is <strong><span class="pull-right"  id="roi_value">10</span>
                                    </strong>
                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" data-slider="true" value="10.2" data-slider-range="8,16" data-slider-step=".05" data-slider-snap="true" id="roi">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="bg-light pinside30 outline">
                                            Monthly EMI
                                            <h2 id='emi' class="pull-right"></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="bg-light pinside30 outline">
                                            Total Interest
                                            <h2 id='tbl_int' class="pull-right"></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="bg-light pinside30 outline"> Payable Amount
                                            <h2 id='tbl_full' class="pull-right"></h2></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="bg-light pinside30 outline">
                                            Interest Percentage
                                            <h2 id='tbl_int_pge' class="pull-right"></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                        <div id="loantable" class='table table-striped table-bordered loantable table-responsive'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.content end -->
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#la").bind(
            "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
                $("#la_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
                calculateEMI();
            }
        );

        $("#nm").bind(
            "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
                $("#nm_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
                calculateEMI();
            }
        );

        $("#roi").bind(
            "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
                $("#roi_value").html(data.value.toFixed(2)); 
                calculateEMI();
            }
        );

        function calculateEMI(){
            var loanAmount = $("#la_value").html();
            var numberOfMonths = $("#nm_value").html();
            var rateOfInterest = $("#roi_value").html();
            var monthlyInterestRatio = (rateOfInterest/100)/12;

            var top = Math.pow((1+monthlyInterestRatio),numberOfMonths);
            var bottom = top -1;
            var sp = top / bottom;
            var emi = ((loanAmount * monthlyInterestRatio) * sp);
            var full = numberOfMonths * emi;
            var interest = full - loanAmount;
            var int_pge =  (interest / full) * 100;
            $("#tbl_int_pge").html(int_pge.toFixed(2)+" %");
            //$("#tbl_loan_pge").html((100-int_pge.toFixed(2))+" %");

            var emi_str = emi.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            var loanAmount_str = loanAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            var full_str = full.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            var int_str = interest.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

            $("#emi").html(emi_str);
            $("#tbl_emi").html(emi_str);
            $("#tbl_la").html(loanAmount_str);
            $("#tbl_nm").html(numberOfMonths);
            $("#tbl_roi").html(rateOfInterest);
            $("#tbl_full").html(full_str);
            $("#tbl_int").html(int_str);
            var detailDesc = "<thead><tr class='table-head'><th>Payment No.</th><th>Begining Balance</th><th>Monthly Payments</th><th>Principal</th><th>Interest</th><th>Ending Balance</th></thead><tbody>";
            var bb=parseInt(loanAmount);
            var int_dd =0;var pre_dd=0;var end_dd=0;
            for (var j=1;j<=numberOfMonths;j++){
                int_dd = bb * ((rateOfInterest/100)/12);
                pre_dd = emi.toFixed(2) - int_dd.toFixed(2);
                end_dd = bb - pre_dd.toFixed(2);
                detailDesc += "<tr><td>"+j+"</td><td>"+bb.toFixed(2)+"</td><td>"+emi.toFixed(2)+"</td><td>"+pre_dd.toFixed(2)+"</td><td>"+int_dd.toFixed(2)+"</td><td>"+end_dd.toFixed(2)+"</td></tr>";
                bb = bb - pre_dd.toFixed(2);
            }
                detailDesc += "</tbody>";
                $("#loantable").html(detailDesc);

        }
        calculateEMI();

    });
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jQuery 3.0 `bind()` is deprecated, consider using `on()`.

To change your the slider to input you need to change `slider:changed` to `input` event and change `toFixed()` to `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

```
$("#la").on("input", function() {
  $("#la_value").html(parseInt(this.value));
  calculateEMI();
});

$("#nm").on("input", function() {
  $("#nm_value").html(parseInt(this.value));
  calculateEMI();
});

$("#roi").on("input", function() {
  $("#roi_value").html(parseFloat(this.value));
  calculateEMI();
});
```

and don't forget to remove

```
<script src="/pio2018/static/cssnew/js/simple-slider.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden input field below slider so you can use that field. You don' t have to create another one since js and or server side language are definetly taking value from that field.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking something like this calculator [mortgage calculator](https://calculate123.com/mortgage)

you can change is to type text and get the value from the input!
remove everything related to the slider and add just the input

Change it from

```
       $("#la").bind(
        "slider:changed", function (event, data) {              
            $("#la_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
            calculateEMI();
        }
    );
```

To something like this

```
        $("#la").change(function(event, data){  
      $("#la_value").html(data.value.toFixed(0)); 
            calculateEMI();});
```

Comment: i made the changes but it does not calculate when I manually enter values. It also uses a simple slider js, i'm adding that for reference.